# Magento2 - Is cache invalidation supposed to work properly when index is on-schedule?

Tags: cache, magento2.3.3, index

We have the following problem: Over the night, products are imported via `REST` interface. Now in the morning some categories are shown as empty.

`Indexes` are set on `update-on-schedule`, that means, the `cache invalidation` should happen once the indices are finished.

Is the cache for category pages invalidated via the schedule index or via the product save?